# Print only first unique value for column that ORDER BY in Oracle sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ddl

This script dump tables with columns and comments for Oracle (what I do: dump schema DDL in human readable format without dependency on any external tools, just `sqlplus`, I want to commit this script to SVN so any team member can use it):

```
SELECT dt.table_name, dt.column_name, dt.data_type, dt.data_length, comm.comments
  FROM user_col_comments comm, user_tab_columns dt
  WHERE dt.table_name = comm.table_name
    AND dt.column_name = comm.column_name
  ORDER BY dt.table_name;
```

Output look like:

```
TBL111 COL11 ...
TBL111 COL22 ...
TBL222 COL11 ...
TBL222 COL22 ...
TBL222 COL33 ...
TBL333 COL11 ...
```

To make it more readable I look for way to skip unnecessary `TBLxxx` words:

```
TBL111 COL11 ...
       COL22 ...
TBL222 COL11 ...
       COL22 ...
       COL33 ...
TBL333 COL11 ...
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generate a report using SQL*Plus you can use [`BREAK ON columnname`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10823/ch_six.htm#sthref652) to suppress duplicates in query results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT case 
         when row_number() over (partition by dt.table_name order by dt.table_name) = 1 then dt.table_name
         else null
       end as table_name, 
       dt.column_name, 
       dt.data_type, 
       dt.data_length, 
       comm.comments
FROM user_col_comments comm, user_tab_columns dt
WHERE dt.table_name = comm.table_name
  AND dt.column_name = comm.column_name
ORDER BY dt.table_name, dt.column_id;
```

Comment: Your solution also great because seems to be DB-vendor independent... Thanks!! +1